# How to add jQuery in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code specific to sorting tables.  Since the code is common in most pages I want to make a JS file which will have the code and all the pages using it can reference it from there.

Problem is: How do I add jQuery, and table sorter plugin into that .js file?

I tried something like this:

```
document.writeln('<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>');
```

but this seems to not work.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm just going to second what a few others have said in their answers.  This is not really a good idea.  If you want to control which files are included in one place then use a common file on your server to write the scripts tags (e.g. scripts.php would generate script tags for common js files).

Comment: merge tablesorter and your code. and use server side logic to include when you need it.

Answer (score 224):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js'; // Check https://jquery.com/ for the current version
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I would replace `http://` with `//` for a relative protocol. Assuming that works with the src property.

Comment: @DerFlatulator: i also need to send a variable to this included script. how to do this? like i need to send a variable itemtype = 11 or itemtype=22 to this included js file and then use it in that file accordingly

Comment: `Refused to load the script`

Comment: This doesn't work I replaced script.scr string with the file I downloaded (same directory so just put name of file) and I also tried the Microsoft jQuery host link but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 97):

If you want to include jQuery code from another JS file, this should do the trick:

I had the following in my HTML file:

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="my_jquery.js"></script>
```

I created a separate my_jquery.js file with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: So what, it's still a good answer, and it might help someone else looking for how to do it.
Welcome to stackoverflow, R-The_Master!

Comment: @genesis φ This is currently the top Google result for `jquery include js` and has 13k views lol.

Comment: Damn straight! certainly helped me out :P. Awesome!

Comment: Helped me out... 3 years later :)

Comment: I just want to point out: The order that you include your js files is important.

Comment: worked for me too.. so simple and straight forward :)

Answer (score 21):

You can use the below code to achieve loading jQuery in your JS file. I have also added a jQuery JSFiddle that is working and it's using a self-invoking function.

```js
// Anonymous "self-invoking" function
(function() {
    var startingTime = new Date().getTime();
    // Load the script
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    // Poll for jQuery to come into existance
    var checkReady = function(callback) {
        if (window.jQuery) {
            callback(jQuery);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(function() { checkReady(callback); }, 20);
        }
    };

    // Start polling...
    checkReady(function($) {
        $(function() {
            var endingTime = new Date().getTime();
            var tookTime = endingTime - startingTime;
            window.alert("jQuery is loaded, after " + tookTime + " milliseconds!");
        });
    });
})();
```

**Other Option** : - You can also try [Require.JS](http://requirejs.org/) which is a JS module loader.

Comment: Thanks @StevenSpyrka for valuable appreciation.

Answer (score 10):

```
/* Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before */

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js";

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = handler;
    script.onload = handler;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);

    function handler(){
       console.log('jquery added :)');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man....That's the answer I needed. Just change the http to https and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

In if you want to add reference to any js file, say, from your project, you may also add it directly using [reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2007/11/06/jscript-intellisense-a-reference-for-the-reference-tag.aspx) tag, in Visual Studio IDE this is handled automatically by dragging and dropping the external file from solution explorer to current file (This works for mark up files, .js & .css files too)

```
/// <reference path="jquery-2.0.3.js" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution, that I adopted as a combination of some proposed solutions in some other forums.

This way you can reference both css files and other js files in one js file, thus making change next time only in a single place. Please let me know if you have any concerns on it.

I have done following:

1. I have created a js with name   jQueryIncluder.js
2. declared and executed following code in this file

   ```
   function getVirtualDirectory() {
     var vDir = document.location.pathname.split('/');
     return '/' + vDir[1] + '/';
   }

   function include_jQueryFilesToPage() {
     var siteAddress = location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + getVirtualDirectory(); 
     var jqCSSFilePath =  siteAddress + 'includes/jQueryCSS/ehrgreen-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css';
     var jqCoreFilePath = siteAddress + 'includes/jquery-1.4.1.min.js';
     var jqUIFilePath =   siteAddress + 'includes/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js';
     var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 

     // jQuery CSS jnclude
     var jqCSS = 'cssIDJQ';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id.
     if (!document.getElementById(jqCSS)) { 
       var link  = document.createElement('link'); 
       link.id  = jqCSS; 
       link.rel  = 'stylesheet'; 
       link.type = 'text/css'; 
       link.href = jqCSSFilePath; 
       link.media = 'all'; 
       head.appendChild(link); 
     } 

     // Core jQuery include
     var jqc = "coreFileRefIDJQ";  
     if (!document.getElementById(jqc)) 
       document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" id="' + jqc + '" src="' + jqCoreFilePath + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');

     // jQueryUI include
     var jqUI = "uiFileRefIDJQ";  
     if (!document.getElementById(jqUI)) 
       document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" id="' + jqUI + '" src="' + jqUIFilePath + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
   }

   include_jQueryFilesToPage();
   ```
3. I referenced the above jQueryIncluder.js file in another js or xsl file of my .Net project as following:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/includes/jQueryIncluder.js"></script>
   ```

I hope my effort is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

it is not possible to import js file inside another js file

**The way to use jquery inside js is**

import the js in the html or whatever view page you are using inside which you are going to include the js file

**view.html**

```
 <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/default.js"></script>
```

**default.js**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('li#user').click(function() {
         $(this).addClass('selectedEmp');
    });
});
```

this will definitely work for you

Answer (score 5):

The following answer was posted previously by another user, but provided no explanation so I decided to annotate what is happening.

```
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
```

## Explanation

The problem is solved by creating a script element in JavaScript, and then setting the `src` attribute to the path of the jQuery file.

```
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
```

Above we create the `script` element.

Next we set the `src` attribute to the path as explained before.
This can be set to

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
```

or

```
/your/path/to/jquery/file
```

In use:

```
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
```

Last, but not least, appending the new element to the document `head`:

```
document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
```

or `body`:

```
document.body.appendChild(jQueryScript);
```

## In Use

```js
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);

setTimeout(function() {
  // Add the rest of your code here, as we have to wait a moment before the document has jQuery as a part of it.
  $("body").html("<h1>It Works!</h1>");
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you're using `</script>` within the script, which is ending the script tag. Try this:

```
document.writeln('<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></sc'+'ript>');
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></sc'+'ript>');
```

Comment: this solution does nothing, as the `script` tag was already being seen as a string, not as markup.

Answer (score 4):

Theres a plugin for jquery where you can just include the files you need into some other js file, here is the link for it http://tobiasz123.wordpress.com/2007/08/01/include-script-inclusion-jquery-plugin/.

Also this document.write line will write the script tags in the html not in your js file.

So I hope this could help you out, a little with your problem

Comment: This link is no longer available

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want to do is still to incude this js file in you html dom, if so then this apporach will work.

1. Write your jquery code in your javascript file as you 
              would in your html dom
2. Include jquery framework before closing body tag
3. Include javascript file after including jqyery file

Example:
 //js file

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     alert("jquery in js file");
     });
```

//html dom

```
    <body>
   <!--some divs content--->

   <script src=/path/to/jquery.js ></script>
   <script src=/path/to/js.js ></script>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you frequently want to update your jquery file link to a new version file, across your site on many pages, at one go..

Create a javascript file (.js) and put in the below code, and map this javascript file to all the pages (instead of mapping jquery file directly on the page), so when the jquery file link is updated on this javascript file it will reflect across the site.

The below code is tested and it works good!

```
document.write('<');
document.write('script ');
document.write('src="');
//next line is the path to jquery file
document.write('/javascripts/jquery-1.4.1.js');
document.write('" type="text/javascript"></');
document.write('script');
document.write('>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a master page base without included js and jquery files. Put a content place holder in master page base in head section, then create a nested master page that inherits from this master page base. Now put your includes in a asp:content in nested master page, finally create a content page from this nested master page

Example:

```
//in master page base    

<%@  master language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="MasterPage" codebehind="MasterPage.master.cs" %>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="cphChildHead">
        <!-- Nested Master Page include Codes will sit Here -->
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <!-- some code here -->
</body>
</html>

//in nested master page :
<%@  master language="C#" masterpagefile="~/MasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="true"
    codebehind="MasterPageLib.master.cs" inherits="sampleNameSpace" %>
<asp:Content ID="headcontent" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphChildHead" runat="server">
    <!-- includes will set here a nested master page -->
    <link href="../CSS/pwt-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- other includes ;) -->
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="bodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphChildBody" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
        <!-- Content page code will sit Here -->
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic adding jQuery, CSS from js file.
When we added onload function to body we can use jQuery to create page from js file.

```js
init();

function init()
{
 addJQuery();
 addBodyAndOnLoadScript();
 addCSS();
}

function addJQuery()
{
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0];
 var scriptjQuery = document.createElement( 'script' );
 scriptjQuery.type = 'text/javascript';
 scriptjQuery.id = 'jQuery'
 scriptjQuery.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js';
 var script = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' )[0];
 head.insertBefore(scriptjQuery, script);
}

function addBodyAndOnLoadScript()
{
 var body = document.createElement('body')
 body.onload = 
 function()
 {
  onloadFunction();
 };
}

function addCSS()
{
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0];
 var linkCss = document.createElement( 'link' );
 linkCss.rel = 'stylesheet';
 linkCss.href = 'E:/Temporary_files/temp_css.css';
 head.appendChild( linkCss );
}

function onloadFunction()
{
 var body = $( 'body' );
 body.append('<strong>Hello world</strong>');
}
```

```css
html 
{
 background-color: #f5f5dc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Temp Study HTML Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="E:\Temporary_files\temp_script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If document.write('<\script ...') isn't working, try document.createElement('script')...

Other than that, you should be worried about the type of website you're making - do you really think its a good idea to include .js files from .js files?

Answer (score 0):

just copy the code from the two files into your file at the top.

or use something like this http://code.google.com/p/minify/ to combine your files dynamically.

Josh

Answer (score 0):

I find that the best way is to use this...

```
**<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>**
```

This is from the Codecademy 'Make an Interactive Website' project.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research, I solve this issue with hint from [ofir_aghai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36343063/1448980) answer about script load event.

Basically we need to use `$` for jQuery code, but we can't use it till jQuery is loaded. I used `document.createElement()` to add a script for jQuery, but the issue is that it takes time to load while the next statement in JavaScript using `$` fails. So, I used the below solution.

**myscript.js** is having code which uses jQuery
**main.js** is used to load both *jquery.min.js* and *myscript.js* files making sure that jQuery is loaded.

main.js code

```
window.load = loadJQueryFile();
var heads = document.getElementsByTagName('head');

function loadJQueryFile(){
    var jqueryScript=document.createElement('script');
    jqueryScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    jqueryScript.setAttribute("src", "/js/jquery.min.js");

    jqueryScript.onreadystatechange = handler;
    jqueryScript.onload = handler;  
    heads[0].appendChild(jqueryScript);
}

function handler(){
    var myScriptFile=document.createElement('script');
    myScriptFile.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    myScriptFile.setAttribute("src", "myscript.js");
    heads[0].appendChild(myScriptFile);
 }
```

This way it worked. Using `loadJQueryFile()` from *myscript.js* didn't work. It immediately goes to the next statement which uses `$`.

Answer (score 0):

The latest answer is outdated, try this:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');  
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -3):

Why are you using Javascript to write the script tags? Simply add the script tags to your head section. So your document will look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Whatever you want here -->
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    The contents of the page.
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am talking about JS files. how to add jQuery reference to a JS file

Comment: Jash, you can't do it. Script files can't be referenced in other script files.

Comment: Yes they can, Canavar. AS far as the browser is concerned, it doesn't matter whether you're adding script tags in the HTML or in a script itself, because it interprets the result the same.