# How to serve up different javascript files by browser width

Tags: javascript, browser, width

So I want certain Javascript files for certain browser widths.  I know that @media serves up specific CSS per browser width and some devices.
How would I do something similar for Javascript files, WITHOUT using server side calls?

Is is possible with Javascript to call other Javascript files based on browser width?
If so, How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need different javascript files? What happens if the user resizes the window?

Comment: I know something like this would be great using media queries. A lot of elements that would need the js no longer exist with a mobile style sheet. Personally I'd like to stop js loading altogether if the browser drops below a certain width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm unsure on why, you can always import JavaScript files through JS Script.

The following links give some information on this.

- http://www.kevinleary.net/loadexternal-javascript-jquery-getscript/
- http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140402/how-to-add-jquery-in-js-file
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

ON a side note - Why are you looking at doing this? Surely you can get the resolution of the screen and then adjust calculations / content based on those variables without the need to change JS files. There are so many different resolutions (mobile devises, multiple monitors, wide screen, projectors etc.).  A user can also re-size the browsers effectively making this not worth it.

Comment: I am looking at this mainly to switch out accordion menus for a mobile window size and a fade in menu for our desktop browser sizes.

Comment: @Carlos: I don't think I know of a single site these days that uses their desktop page for it's mobile device. I'd save yourself the head-ache and look in to browser forwarding and worry more about the site itself. Besides, unless you have a **very**  simple site, chances are you're going to want to streamline it for mobile anyways (cut media, excess graphics, etc.)

Answer (score 13):

```
var scriptSrc = 'js/defaults.js';
if (screen.width <= 800)
  scriptSrc = 'js/defaults-800.js';
else if (screen.width <= 1024)
  scriptSrc = 'js/defaults-1024.js';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = scriptSrc;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(script);
```

Perhaps? Dynamic-load them based on screen resolution. Could also use document size, browser size, etc. Though I'm not positive you really want to be doing this. **Ideally though you should be dealing with relative metrics (like % or em) in your design and avoid this.**

Comment: II have tried something simliar with jQuery by setting an id to the default script tag and then switching out the file based on that. I may try it your way, in Firebug I got an error with the page trying to load the file. All paths are correct, but I may just append it doing it this way.

Comment: Do you think I could use this to omit certain files as well?

Comment: @Carlos: Yes, you can. Just the key is they need to be avoided in the load process until you need/want them. Can;t unload a file you already loaded without doing some serious re-declarations. If you wanted to get fancy you could either make the scripts run based on relative size, make several versions but bind it to one common accessor, or just continue on this path and load what applies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")

if (window.document.body.clientWidth == XXX) {
    fileref.setAttribute("src", "script1.js")
} else {
    fileref.setAttribute("src", "script2.js")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are a good solution for providing alternative styles for different window widths. Unfortunately, there is no `media` attribute for the `<script>` element to proceed similarly.

You can, however, provide a script-loading script which will load desired `.js` file depending on the style sheet selected by the browser on the basis of your media query. I don't know how to do this in a direct, elegant way but there is a nice hack for that. You have to "mark" each `.css` with a unique declaration (dummy, unimportant or different by design) and check it from within JS after the page has loaded to determine which style sheet has been applied by the browser.

The HTML could look like this:

```
<style media="handheld, screen and (max-width:1023px)">
    body { margin-top: 0px }
</style>
<style media="screen and (min-width:1024px)">
    body { margin-top: 1px }
</style>
```

And the accompanying JS as follows:

```
function onLoad() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var mark = window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('margin-top');

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', mark=='0px' ? 'handheld.js' : 'screen.js');
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

This does the job, but only on a per-load basis. To get a responsive reaction to resizing the browser's window by the user, you should keep track on the widow's width and reload the page when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2011 the world has shifted into the mobile era.

You might wanna try with: `document.documentElement.clientWidth`, as it will tell you the visible area of your page - it reacts to zoom but not to pitch.