# Can I execute javascript based on window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have a responsive site where I'm using a javascript to create a sticky sidebar.

I'm also using media queries to change from a multi-column layout to a single-column layout when the browser size is less than 768px.

I need to figure out how to disable the sticky menu script in the single-column layout. Essentially, I need something like a media query for the script statement.

This is the code I'm using to enable the script:

```
<script>
jQuery('#info').containedStickyScroll({
        duration: 0,
        unstick: false
    });
</script>
```

Is there something I can add to it to only have it trigger if the window is 768px wide or wider?

EDIT: I'm looking for a solution that will work if the user resizes the window on the fly.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811238/how-to-serve-up-different-javascript-files-by-browser-width/4811342#4811342

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
     $(window).resize(function(){
         if($(this).width() >= 768){
             jQuery('#info').containedStickyScroll({
                 duration: 0,
                 unstick: false
             });
         }
      })
      .resize();//trigger resize on page load
});
```

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL This works based on the window size at page load; is there a way to make it work if the user resizes the page after it is loaded?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - I thought OP needs only when the width should be 768 but yest `>=` should be better.

Comment: IME it's best to debounce the resize handler since this event can be fired a _lot_ while the window is resized. I like this jQuery plugin: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Thanks. The updated code works if the window starts small and is enlarged beyond 768, but not if the window starts large and is reduced below 768.

Comment: If the window width is reduced below 768 then the `if` condition will fail and it will not do anything. If you want to do something else in this case then have a `else` block and write the required code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var height = $(window).height(); //I'm assuming you mean height, you can try .width() if yo u need it

if (height < 768) {
  jQuery('#info').containedStickyScroll({
      duration: 0,
      unstick: false
  });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
var targetWidth = 768;
if ( $(window).width() &gt;= targetWidth) {     
  //Add your javascript for screens wider than or equal to 768 here
  jQuery('#info').containedStickyScroll({
      duration: 0,
      unstick: false
  });
}
else {
  //Add your javascript for screens smaller than 768 here
  console.log(`am less than ${targetWidth}`)
}
```