# Execute function based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a specific function based on screen size and screen size changes **(Responsive)**

So lets say I have 3 functions *(For Example)*

```
function red() {
    $('div').css('background','#B60C0C')
    .text('Screen Size RED');
    console.log('RED');
}

function orange() {
    $('div').css('background','#EBAE10')
    .text('Screen Size ORANGE');
    console.log('ORANGE');
}

function green() {
    $('div').css('background','#83ba2b')
    .text('Screen Size GREEN');
    console.log('GREEN');
}
```

I need to execute function green() when the screen width size 500px or lower

And function orange() when the screen width size 501px to 850px

And function red() when the screen width size 851px or higher

[image]

I tried to use resize() but the problem is executing the function when resizing the browser for each pixel repeat executing the same function and this is a very bad way to perform

**I need to execute the function when break the point of the screen width size**

Ready to use code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BaNRq/

Comment: looks like you're updating styles. why not use `media queries` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?

Comment: Do we have unreal JavaScript functions?

Comment: @Jim Right way to do this is using the media queries... Especially for responsive design media queries is what you should look upto.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326349/can-i-execute-javascript-based-on-window-size

Comment: @todd i think it's not..

Comment: @Vainglory07 no? They're not identical but, essentially, they want the same thing: to trigger a specific function on a screen size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meh; here's a solution.

You could cache the lastBoundry determined to invoke the functions **only when a change occurs**.

```
// define the boundries
var bounds = [
    {min:0,max:500,func:red},
    {min:501,max:850,func:orange},
    {min:851,func:green}
];

// define a resize function. use a closure for the lastBoundry determined.
var resizeFn = function(){
    var lastBoundry; // cache the last boundry used
    return function(){
        var width = window.innerWidth; // get the window's inner width
        var boundry, min, max;
        for(var i=0; i<bounds.length; i++){
            boundry = bounds[i];
            min = boundry.min || Number.MIN_VALUE;
            max = boundry.max || Number.MAX_VALUE;
            if(width > min && width < max 
               && lastBoundry !== boundry){
                lastBoundry = boundry;
                return boundry.func.call(boundry);            
            }
        }
    }
};
$(window).resize(resizeFn()); // bind the resize event handler
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize'); // on load, init the lastBoundry
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BaNRq/3/

Comment: I need slightly modification to this code, I removed .trigger() to make the default html (gray background) showing first thing to the user wherever he is, but the problem is when the user change the browser size the current setting size function (yellow) execute after 1px change, I need to execute this (yellow) if the user go and back again from (green) or (red) http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/BaNRq/6/ , And thank you very much for your time :), I hope I've explained well

Comment: @Jim I need a bit more info. I don't quite get the last part of your requirement. "i need to execute this if the user go and back again". Please clarify?

Comment: Thank you @NirvanaTikku I did find a solution and It works for me as I expected but I don't know if It good or bad way to solve this, check here http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/BaNRq/7/show/ and resize the browser to another size to execute.

Answer (score 9):

I actually wanted to put this as a comment to @Nirvana Tikku's answer, however I can't since I don't have 50 reputation, so I'll comment here + I'll add a my own solution so the answer space wouldn't be wasted.

### Comment:

I'm sorry to (perhaps) "ruin the party", but either I didn't get the OP's question right or maybe I'm misunderstanding the solution.
Here's what I think the OP wanted: a way to execute a function dynamically based on screen size and **without executing the function for each pixel repeat**.
In the given solution, though it's quite difficult too see at first, the function **do execute for each pixel**. Try to put *console.log('aaaa')* in between the return function lines like so:

```
    return function(){
 console.log('aaaa')
        var width = window.innerWidth; // get the window's inner width
```

Run the function, then hit F12 button (in Firefox) and resize the window you'll see it shoots up the entire resizing time (sorry can't upload images either - not enough rep').

I've just spent an entire day trying to replicate this solution on my own,
so that I'd be able to execute a function based on screen-size but without it 'listening' to every pixel along the way.

So far, it seems impossible (unless someone who reads this has a solution), in the meanwhile here's my code, which IMHO is way less complex.

### Solution:

```
var widths = [0, 500, 850];

function resizeFn() {
if (window.innerWidth>=widths[0] && window.innerWidth<widths[1]) {
red();
} else if (window.innerWidth>=widths[1] && window.innerWidth<widths[2]) {
orange();
} else {
green();
}
}
window.onresize = resizeFn;
resizeFn();
```

see it works in https://jsfiddle.net/BaNRq/16/

BTW this is answer is practically the same as @Vainglory07 minus the jQuery

Comment: window.onresize = function is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the monitor's resolution settings, consider [`window.screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.screen), for instance I am using `1280 x 1024` so mine reports

```
window.screen.height; // 1024
window.screen.width;  // 1280
```

You could also use the `avail` prefix to ignore things like the task bar. If you just want to work out the browser's visible area then you would use [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight) and [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth) on the `documentElement`, i.e.

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth;  // 1263 (the scrollbar eats up some)
document.documentElement.clientHeight; //  581 (lots lost here, e.g. to console)
```

---

As for your fires-too-often problem, introduce a rate limiter, e.g.

```
function rateLimit(fn, rate, notQueueable) {
    var caninvoke = true, queable = !notQueueable,
        ready, limiter,
        queue = false, args, ctx;
    notQueueable = null;
    ready = function () { // invokes queued function or permits new invocation
        var a, c;
        if (queable && queue) {
            a = args; c = ctx;
            args = ctx = null; queue = false; // allow function to queue itself
            fn.apply(c, a);
            setTimeout(ready, rate); // wait again
        } else
            caninvoke = true;
    }
    limiter = function () { // invokes function or queues function
        if (caninvoke) {
            caninvoke = false;
            fn.apply(this, arguments);
            setTimeout(ready, rate); // wait for ready again
        } else
            args = arguments, ctx = this, queue = true;
    };
    return limiter;
}

var myRateLimitedFunction = rateLimit(
    function () {console.log('foo');},
    2e3 // 2 seconds
);
myRateLimitedFunction(); // logged
myRateLimitedFunction(); // logged after rate limit reached
```

Comment: I'm really trying hard to understand and figure out how to use your code, and still trying. sorry but I'm a newbie to Javascript :$

Comment: @Jim `rateLimit` is a _function_ which returns a _function_. The returned _function_ is the first parameter `fn` in a special wrapper. The second parameter `rate` specifies the minimum number of _milliseconds_ to wait between letting the _function_ be invoked. The third parameter `notQueueable` is optional and disables the ability for the _function_ to invoke itself immediately when the minimum wait time has expired, if it was attempted to be invoked before that time was up.

Comment: I know the ability for it to queue makes it look a lot more complicated, but I wanted to make sure that the very last pixel of your resize was always accounted for. If it was limited with no queue, it would not always be the case. The queue system I wrote for it only does the very last invocation attempt, so don't worry about thousands being queued - only one will.

Comment: Just to be explicit the parameter types should be; `fn` _function_, `rate` _integer_, `notQueueable` _(optional) boolean_.

Answer (score 3):

Using javascript, you may get the value of screen size. And from that you can call your custom functions to get what you want.

```
 //function for screen resize
 function screen_resize() {
        var h = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
        var w = parseInt(window.innerWidth);

        if(w <= 500) {
            //max-width 500px
            // actions here...
            red();
        } else if(w > 500 && w <=850) {
            //max-width 850px
            // actions here...
            orange();
        } else {
            // 850px and beyond
            // actions here...
            green();
        }

    }
```

I used window.innerHeight/innerWidth to get the height/width of screen without/disregarding the scrollbars.

```
    // if window resize call responsive function
    $(window).resize(function(e) {
        screen_resize();
    });
```

and on resize just call the function and also auto call the function on page.ready state.

```
    // auto fire the responsive function so that when the user
    // visits your website in a mall resolution it will adjust
    // to specific/suitable function you want
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        screen_resize();
    });
```

Try to check the output here: [OUTPUT :)](http://jsfiddle.net/BaNRq/1/)

hope this helps..

Comment: Just one problem is that your code executing the function when resizing the browser for each pixel repeat executing the same function, check the consloe here http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/BaNRq/2/show/ ,Resize the broswer and see what is happining

Comment: well, im just giving you my idea about that :) It's up to you what to choose or to use. Modify to meet what you really want to achieve? Thanks @Jim.

Comment: I've reached to the same result with .resize() http://api.jquery.com/resize/ but this was my main problem with my code, check out the end of my question above, Thanx for your time anyway :)

Comment: @Vainglory07 when I read the question I took that the key bit was `I tried to use resize() but the problem is executing the function when resizing the browser for each pixel repeat executing the same function and this is a very bad way to perform` -- i.e. `How can I make the function not fire for each pixel changed?`, just it was hidden away right at the end. Hence why my answer has a huge piece of code for rate limiting a function, which I hoped would satisfy the requirements of OP.