# Execute Jscript only at certain width without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, execute, jscript

Okay so with much attempt to no prevail, I have been trying to change the order of the below divs using the following JScript command (without jQuery) **only** when the window is at a certain width; **particularly 1024px and below**. The JScript used is successful in executing and subsequently changing the order of the divs, however it occurs at all widths.

I wish for **box-3** to be above **box-1** when the window width is equal to or less than **1024px** (without using jQuery).

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
  <div class="box-3"></div>
  <div class="box-4"></div>
 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var content = document.querySelector('.box-3');
 var parent = content.parentNode;
 parent.insertBefore(content, parent.firstChild);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: Question is different from "Execute function based on screen size" (Authored by Jim) because solutions given to Jim included - and accepted - jQuery, whereas this question is purely for vanilla Javascript*

Comment: What have you tried to make it only occur on the screen sizes you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute function based on screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371122/execute-function-based-on-screen-size)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have read that but find it difficult to understand/translate to my needs :/

Comment: @SidTheBeard a variety of 'onresize' function, mq etc, but to be honest I'm not 100% sure of their particular function, I am new to Jscript and trying to put the pieces together haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so you were on the right track using `window.onresize`.

**A suggested edit and a good point**:

If you want the reorder to happen before the window is resized, make sure you check the size of window when the page is opened by using `window.onload`. To make everything more concise you can put your reorder code into a function, let's say `myResizeFunction()` and then do something like this

```
var needsReset = false;
window.onresize = function() {
    if( this.innerWidth <= 1024 ) {
        myResizeFunction();
    } else {
        if( needsReset ) {
            //UNDO THE REORDER OR
            //WHATEVER CODE YOU WANT IF SCREEN IS LARGER THAN TARGET SIZE
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    if( this.innerWidth <= 1024 ) {
        myResizeFunction();
    }
    //NO ELSE BLOCK NEEDED BECAUSE
    //IF SCREEN SIZE ISN'T IN TARGET RANGE WE HAVE NOTHING TO UNDO
}
function myResizeFunction() {
    //NOW YOUR REORDER CODE LIVES HERE
    //SET needsReset TO true BECAUSE WE'VE CHANGED THE ORDER OF ELEMENTS
    needsReset = true;
}
```

I’m on a mobile so I can’t test how the DOM is changing but try `parent.lastChild` instead.

If you’re removing the `.box-3` and then inserting it in front of `.box-1` (I believe this is what is happening) then doing a `insertBefore` on the `parent.lastChild` should put box 3 back in its original spot

Comment: Thank you, that worked in executing when width was 1024, but unsure how to undo the reorder - tried parent.insertBefore(content, parent.fourthChild); but dont believe that is right :/

Comment: @KAindex try the changes I made and see if that works.

Comment: I dont believe it is working, it may be on my end I'm not sure, but when the width is expanded, yes box-3 is in its original position, but then the slightest change in width, even by 1 pixel, either expanding or shrinking the width, sends box-3 last :/

Comment: @KAindex I added a boolean variable that you need to check, if the variable is true then the elements need to be reset. Otherwise, the elements will stay as is.

Comment: I have applied this however, 'parent.lastChild' still inserts box-3 after the "lastChild" which is box-4, instead of just before it?

Comment: I’ll have to give it a look when I get to my desktop, I’ll @ you when I get to it

Comment: #SidTheBeard Thanks

Comment: @KAindex I figured it out, instead of parent.lastChild you need to use parent.lastElementChild. Checkout this codepen https://codepen.io/SidTheBeard/pen/rJRYRL?editors=1111