# Is it normal behaviour that chrome load both my responsive css files?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I try to load different CSS files for the mobile and desktop version of my website like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="home.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" href="home-mobile.css" />
```

But when I check on Chrome, both my files are loaded. The only thing is that the priority of home-mobile.css is Highest and home.css is Lowest on low width and vice versa.

How to have only the home-mobile.css loaded on a real mobile ?

Answer (score 1):

**It is the expected behavior.**
By doing what you have asked, your site will not be responsive.
A responsive page is designed to be adapted to different resolutions (phones and tablets can have different resolutions as well) and doing so while having all the CSS on demand without making a request for them upon resolution resize.

You can minify your CSS for less traffic.

However, if you insist, vis JavaScript, you could make a listener in order to figure out when the user on specific `media` and add the CSS tag to the DOM. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371763/1918287) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I second Maor Refaeli's answer, however it might be possible to load it like this.

```js
if (screen && screen.width < 480) {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="home-mobile.css" />;
}
```

Comment: Hoped for a pure html solution but will go for the js one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely normal. What you want is to have some sort of device sniffing code that will switch between 2 css when mobile is detected. if you're using PHP for back-end you may use something like

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

in order to detect the agent, but you cannot rely on snippets like this, since this info may not be set in the HTTP header. My advice, load your files and as Maor Refaeli sugested just minify them...