# if statements - $(window).width() not working so well in Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, if-statement, viewport

Good Day

I want to execute 2 statements based on the window width or Viewport size:
Here is my code:

```
var w = $(window).width();

if (w > 767){run myFunc()};

if (w < 767){run myFunc()}; //But this function has different CSS Values
```

The problem:

in Chrome and IE (not FF), **only the second if statement is executed**, doesn't matter that the viewport size is...

Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: The question is where/when are you calling this snippet?

Comment: Why not printing out 'w' variable to see the actual size

Comment: Not self-citing to promote, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811238/how-to-serve-up-different-javascript-files-by-browser-width) deals with JS files based on windows size and may be helpful.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/DZ9DX/2/embedded/result/ - are you sure you're updating the `w` variable with the current width and not hardcoding it on load?

Comment: @Jaay - When printing out the variables, they show  fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to wrap it inside an `resize` `event-handler`...

Works like a charm for me:

```
var myFunc = function(arg){
    console.log(arg);
};

$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();

    if (w > 767) myFunc(1);
    if (w < 767) myFunc(2);
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ms3u5/

Comment: thanks. But what exactly does the top function do? (var myFunc = function(arg).... ?

Comment: @DextrousDave It logs the passed `argument` in the `console`. So if tje `window`-width is smaller than `767` it logs `2` otherwise `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this...

```
function myFunc() {
  if ($(window).width() > 767) {
  //then do something
  }else{
  //do something else
  }
}
```

...but I would also agree with yckart, you probably meant to include the re-size method.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
```