# access js file from another website

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, web-deployment

In IIS, i have a website under which there are various virtual directories. I want to access/link JS file from one virtual directory into another. So, basically i have an application (in virtual dir 1) from which i want to link JS files being used in another application (virtual dir 2). Both these applications are under the same website in IIS.

Also, i am looking at a way of creating a common folder under website from where all applications can link commonly used JS files. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can add reference like...

```
<script src="http://www.website.com/foldername/GeneralMethods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Get an idea from this thread [How to add jQuery in JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140402/how-to-add-jquery-in-js-file)